# web3js metamask function undefined after updating

Tags: web3js, truffle, dapp-development, metamask, javascript

I added a new function `exampleFunc` in solidity the `mycontract.json` file gets updated with that function with public visibility but `web3.eth.contract(abiArray).at(address);` does not contains the newly added function.

```
var con = require('../../build/contracts/MyContract.json');
var keys = Object.keys(con.networks);
var address = con.networks[keys[keys.length-1]].address;
var abiArray = con.abi;


componentDidMount(){
        const web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
        this.instance = web3.eth.contract(abiArray).at(address);
        console.log(this.instance);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete your 'build' folder and recompile..for some reason its like a magic cure when it comes to truffle